# Complementary Projective operator in time-independent non degenerate perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I have some difficulties when I am reading time-independent perturbation theory of Sakurai's book "Modern Quantum Mechanics" p.290. Let me introduce the background of this question first. Originally, the unperturbed Schrödinger's equation is:

\begin{equation}
H_{0}|n^{0}> = E^{0}_{n}|n^{0}>
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $|n^{0}>$ is the unperturbed eigenstates. However, if there is a small perturbation that perturbes the system, the Schrödinger's equation becomes the follows:
\begin{equation}
(H_{0}+\lambda V)|n> = E_{n}|n>
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
$\lambda V$ is the perturbation of the system and $\lambda$ is a real parameter to control the perturbation.

We denote the energy difference of the perturbed energy and the unperturbed energy as $\Delta_{n} = E_{n} - E^{0}_{n}$

Then, Sakurai showed the eigenstate $|n> $ as follows:
\begin{equation}
|n> = |n^{0}> + \frac{1}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}\phi_{n}(\lambda V- \Delta_{n})|n>
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
And $\phi_{n}$ is the complementary projective operator 
\begin{equation}
\phi_{n} = 1 - |n^{0}><n^{0}| = \Sigma_{k \neq n} |k^{0}><k^{0}| 
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

The difficulties that I encountered is the following, Sakurai said that it was customary to write:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}\phi_{n} \rightarrow \frac{\phi_{n}}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

and similarly

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}\phi_{n} = \phi_{n}\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}= \phi_{n}\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}\phi_{n}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}

The order of the operator is important as operators are not commute in general. Therefore, I do not know why Sakurai can "customary" to write equation(5) . Besides, Why Sakurai can change the order of $\phi_{n}$ and $\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n}-H_{0}}$, and multiply $\phi_{n}$ at both left and right of $\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n}-H_{0}}$ in equation(6)$. Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

By "customary" he means this is a "shorthand" for eqn. (5.1.24). We are supposed to understand this as:

1) Consider the restriction of ${E^{0}_{n} - H_{0}}$  to the complement space as an operator (call it $G$) in that space.

2) $G$ is strictly positive so it has an inverse  *as an operator in that space*: $G^{-1}$.

3) Form an operator on the full space equal to $G^{-1}$ on the complement space and $x$ on the $n^0$ space. $x$ can be any number, it doesn't matter since the full operator will always be be used with a projection operator on one side.

Comment: BTW, it is [here](http://kgut.ac.ir/useruploads/1505647831850hcd.pdf), p.307 or p. 326 of the PDF.

Comment: Thank you @Keith McClary for solving my question. Besides, I want to ask why Sakurai can multiply the complementary operator at both left and right hand sides of inverse operator $1/( E^{0}_{n} -H_{0}) $ ?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if he wrote $({E^{0}_{n}-H_{0}})^\perp$ for the operator in the complement space and $(\frac{1}{E^{0}_{n}-H_{0}})^\perp$ for it's inverse as an operator in that space. Since the domain and range of the operators are in the complement space, you can put the projection on either side and consider the result as an operator in the full space.